# Convert a train object of Caret

Tags: r, caret

I developed a logistic model with loss function in Caret ("regLog") but I can't then use it in other packages (package car for VIF, package performance..) always giving me the same reason: "no applicable method for ' vcov' applied to an object of class "c('train', 'train.formula')"".
Is it possible to change the class of a caret object?
Otherwise it means that caret cannot be integrated with other packages

Comment: What is your R version?

Comment: Hi Juan, my R version is 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)

Comment: I see, you have a functional version of R because there are version that used to be problems.

Comment: It surprises me how a historic and functional R library like Caret has problems integrating with other packages. Alternatively, they would have had to internally develop functions capable of offering the same functionalities typical of a linear model (multicollinearity search, influence point, error distribution study)

Comment: It might be that functions used by Caret, are in other packages. I mean, there are functions with the same name but different libraries that have different targets. For this reason, I think it is essential to use two points. (e.g. namelibrary::namefunction).  I agree with you, internally develop functions, I guess they had some of them.